# Using iOS iPad2 to Connect and Logon to Java Server Running HTTP Service

Tags: java, ios, xcode, dns, bonjour

I am writing an iOS 5.1.1 app for the iPad2 using Xcode 4.4.1. I want to be able to locate a local http server running on Java.

Once I am able to connect to the http server, all I need to communicate with it is the url including the port.

**My questions:**

1) Should I use Bonjour or a DNS Server running on the http server to discover the http server itself?

2) I need to authenticate the iPad2 user with name and password to work with the http server once I discover it.

I need some help understanding how I would go about accomplishing these two steps including source code if available for the iOS 5 and Xcode 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Bonjour is pretty easy to tie in with Java apps. If you're particularly masochistic you can write your own Java-based mDNS (Bonjour) responders (I've done it, it's not rocket science), but the quickest way to get going is to use [jMDNS](https://github.com/quelgar/jmdns) in your http server to advertise its existence. I won't copy & paste the code samples but they suffice for most applications.

On the iOS side, [NSNetService](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend. Fundamentally it involves starting a responder in the background to look for services (i.e. your Java app), then calling a delegate when something appears/disappears:

```
id delegateObject; // Assume this exists.
NSNetServiceBrowser *serviceBrowser;

serviceBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
[serviceBrowser setDelegate:delegateObject];
[serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_http._tcp" inDomain:@""];
```

There's a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002520-SW2) that explains it all. The protocol hasn't changed for 10+ years and you count on all modern iOS/OS X versions supporting it. The jMDNS library is pretty well battle-tested at this stage, too.

You might consider creating your own service type if you don't want it to be visible to other apps that search for `_http._tcp.`, although this is just a cosmetic thing.

2) The simplest thing that'd work would be HTTP basic auth; you didn't say what kind of authentication your app supports or how you make HTTP requests on the client side, but this is [pretty](http://objective-d.com/?page_id=160) well [covered](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) already.